# In run console image, 5th line from last. Please suggest the corrections

Tags: python, calculator

[enter image description here][1]```

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return(num1 + num2)
def subtract(num1, num2):
    return(num1 - num2)
def multiply(num1, num2):
    return(num1 * num2)
def divide(num1, num2):
    return int(num1 / num2)
operations = {
add,
subtract,
multiply,
divide,
> }
def calculator():
    new_calc = True
    while new_calc:
        num1 = float(input("First number? "))
        for symbol in operations:
            print(symbol)
        should_continue = True
        while should_continue:
            operation_symbol = input("Pick the operation: ")
            num2 = float(input("Next number? "))
            calculation_function = operations[operation_symbol]
            answer = calculation_function(num1, num2)
            print(f"{num1} {operation_symbol} {num2} = {answer}")
            more = input(f"Continue with {answer}? type 'y' or 'n' for again, 'e' for exit..") == "y" or "n" or "e"
            if more == "y":
                num1 = answer
            elif more == "n":
                should_continue = False
            else:
                new_calc = False
calculator()
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dIFW.png
```

Comment: Can you provide concrete example(s) of how this *should* behave?

Comment: Simply remove `== "y" or "n" or "e"`.

Comment: thanks mkrieger1 you're right. Its working.